# Getting a Code: 503 error in running Watson Speech to Text API

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I have been using the Watson API for a long time now, however it has started giving me Code:503 errors recently for the past 4 days and I am rarely able to get the desired output which I used to. The code works fine and is unchanged.

This is the error I am receving.

```
watson_developer_cloud.watson_service.WatsonApiException: Error: <HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Internal Server Error</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Internal Server Error - Write</H1>
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to
complete your request.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;4&#46;327f1cb8&#46;1597063995&#46;c75870b
</BODY></HTML>
, Code: 503
```

Is it because of the overload on IBM cloud during the past couple of days or is there any network issues at my end?

Comment: What is a long time? All the Watson services have been migrated off cloud foundary and hence now all use IAM based authentication, and use different urls for each region. As you said a `503` indicates  service availability, and you may have hit a maintenance window - https://cloud.ibm.com/status?selected=maintenance - but 4 days is a long time. If this is intermittent then raise a ticket against the service. If it is always, then check if you are using an out-dated url / credential combination.

Comment: @chughts Hey. I have been using speech to text API for 4 months now. The bothering part is my code barely changed. I even ran the test on the old code with reduced functionalities (not related to watson which was always present). I will raise a ticket related to it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, I was using NodeJS and adding an extra "/" at the end of the URL seemed to work from the example found here:
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=node#recognize

```
const speechToText = new SpeechToTextV1({
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({
    apikey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  }),
  serviceUrl: 'https://api.us-east.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/',
});
```

^Note the extra "/" at the end of service URL

Comment: Life saving! I wonder why it sometimes fails and sometimes works without slash so it doesn't always generate this error